# How to optimise these loops in R

Tags: r, optimization, for-loop, vectorization

I'm in the process of cleaning data and have ended up with a lot of `for` loops. Since my data set has more than 6 million rows, this is a bit of a problem for me, but I'm not sure how to avoid it.

An example of my data set (called sentencing.df) would be something like:

```
    Ethnicity     PersonNumber

    Caucasian     1
    Caucasian     1
    Unknown       1
    Indian        2
    Indian        2
```

I want to compare within the same person number - for example, I want to know whether the ethnicities for each person number are the same (and then to change the incorrect entries if they exist). My code uses for loops and looks something like this:

```
PersonListRace <- unique(sentencing.df[sentencing.df$ethnicity == "UNKNOWN",]$PersonNumber) 
PersonListRace <- as.numeric(as.character(PersonListRace))
 # vector of person numbers for those with ethnicity UNKNOWN

for (i in 1:100) {
  race <- sentencing.df[sentencing.df$PersonNumber == PersonListRace[i],]$ethnicity
    # creates a vector of unique ethnicities for that person
  if (length(unique(race)) != 2) {next}
    # excludes those who only have UNKNOWN or who have UNKNOWN plus multiple ethnicities
  else {
   label <- as.character(unique(race[which(race != "UNKNOWN")]))
   sentencing.df[sentencing.df$PersonNumber == PersonListRace[i],]$ethnicity <- label
  }
}
```

I then have similar things for all my other variables, and the for loops take far too long to run. I've looked at some of the other questions and answers on the site, but my main problem is that I can't find a way to compare only within the same person number across a different variable, without using a for loop.

Anything that would help me achieve my aim in a practical timeframe would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: If PersonListRace is a factor then this is wrong: `PersonListRace <- as.numeric(PersonListRace)`. Should be `PersonListRace <- as.numeric(as.character(PersonListRace))`. The rest of your code has not been described in natural language very well and your command of R is too weak to allow understanding, for me anyway. Please describe in English what is desire. There are almost certainly more efficient methods available. For instance, is majority vote the arbiter of "correct", and how to handle ties.

Comment: Sorry if it's difficult to understand - I'm still relatively new to R and learning as I go. I'm not sure how else to explain what I need other than what I've said. My final aim is to use the known ethnicities for a person - e.g. caucasian for personnumber 1 - to fill in the blanks in their other entries - so change the "unknown" ethnicity for person 1 also to "caucasian". My problem is that I need to compare the ethnicities for each individual person to do that, and can't figure out how to do that without a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of my concerns were addressed in the comment so I will just take the example as being fully representative of the complexity of the problem (although my experience is that things are rarely so simple);

```
dat <- read.table(text="Ethnicity     PersonNumber
     Caucasian     1
     Caucasian     1
     Unknown       1
     Indian        2
     Indian        2", header=TRUE)
 dat$TrueEth <- with( dat, ave(Ethnicity, PersonNumber, 
                               FUN=function(perE){
                                              unique( perE[perE != "Unknown"] ) } ) )

> dat
  Ethnicity PersonNumber   TrueEth
1 Caucasian            1 Caucasian
2 Caucasian            1 Caucasian
3   Unknown            1 Caucasian
4    Indian            2    Indian
5    Indian            2    Indian
```

The outstanding issues are what to do with more than one value for Ethnicity and if the answer is majority rules what to do if there are an equal number of not-Unknown.

Comment: Ah I see what you were asking now. I have answers to both those queries, currently dealt with by separate for loops, although maybe there is a better way. I actually have two variables, ethnicity1 and ethnicity2. If one ethnicity >80% of entries (excl unknown), that becomes ethnicity1 and ethnicity 2 is NA. Otherwise if there are two ethnicities (excl unknown) which individually make up >20% of entries for the person (e.g. 75-25 split), the most common becomes eth1 and next most common eth2. If neither criterion is met, all become unknown.

Comment: Hmm although I'm now seeing some issues with this.